# Automate cleardown of old table data

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I created a the below postgresql function that deletes data that is older than 6 months from two tables then runs VACUUM. The plan is to automate this to run on a regular schedule

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sales.fn_clear_old_data_from_sales_tables(
    )
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM sales.sales_messages_table b
        USING sales.sales_table a
        WHERE a.sales_id = b.sales_id
        AND a.transaction_timestamp < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 MONTH';

    DELETE FROM sales.sales_table WHERE transaction_timestamp < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 MONTH';
    
    VACUUM ANALYZE sales.pricegenerator_dependency_messages_table;
    VACUUM ANALYZE sales.sales_table;
    RETURN true;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION sales.fn_clear_old_data_from_sales_tables()
    OWNER TO salesdev;
```

Unfortunately when I try to run the function I get this error:

> ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Just don't turn off autovacuum? And you can also configure auto vacuum per table, to be more or less aggressive. imho you never need a manual/scripted VACUUM when autovacuum does it's job.

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74600215/5298879). You [shouldn't really have to manually do `vacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html), but if you want to, you can limit your routine to only do the `delete`, and the `cron`/`pg_cron`/`at` job that calls this function/procedure can issue the `vacuum` command separately, after that.

Comment: That's not possible, check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182258/postgres-vacuum-in-function

Comment: As long as you have `autovacuum`  on you don't need to do this the table will be vacuumed. Remember a regular `VACUMM`(no FULL clause) just marks the space available  for reuse, it does not clear out the data.  If the purpose behind this includes immediately updating the table statistics then just run `ANALYZE` by itself.

Comment: Another option would be to use table partitioning per month, and drop or truncate an entire partition after X time. That completely avoids the need for vacuum. It can be much faster as well. If you drop the partition, there is no need for analyze either.

Comment: To match `a.transaction_timestamp < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 MONTH'` those would have to be 180 daily partitions. Some scenarios can see not just faster drops/deletes but faster everything, thanks to Postgres being more easily convinced to deploy more workers to any task on those. Still, that's *some* scenarios, at *some* volumes: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/85JuZodj) I had it push more and more workers, but for the job at hand, it didn't really cut any exec time.

Comment: @Zegarek,  if you are using partitioning the intent would be to prune partitions on the partition boundaries, in FrankHeikens case by dropping the month partitions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's my point. With monthly partitioning in place, OP needs to continue holding on to records older than 6 months until their whole partition is outdated, then drop it. To only keep records no older than 6 months by dropping partitions rather than targeting deletes, they would have to have daily partitioning. I agree it's unlikely a make or break whether they wipe everything 6 months old, daily, or everything from 6 to 7 months old, monthly.