# Update a column when a related column in another table is updated (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 3 tables, a user_table, a task_pool table, and a task_dispersal table.
The relevant tables, **task_pool** and **task_dispersal**, are related by *order_id*. They are visually shown below with their relevant columns.

The **dispersal table** will periodically be queried to insert x rows into **task_pool** (x being the amount in it's column *amount_to_disperse*). Each row it adds will have a random user_id from the **user_table**, and the related *order_id*.

In **task_pool**, each row has an *expire_time*. It will be periodically queried to update all rows with current_datetime > expire_time; setting their *status* from 0(active) to -1(expired). Since multiple user_id's with the same order_id were inserted, there may be multiple rows with the same order_id that are updated to -1(expired) when the table is queried

This is my query so far:

```
UPDATE task_pool 
SET status = -1 
WHERE 
    status = 0 AND expire_time < current_timestamp
    OR
    status = 1 AND expire_time + (10 * interval '1 minute') < current_timestamp
```

***ISSUE:***

Whenever the rows in *task_pool* are updated to -1(expired), per row updated, I want to increase a counter in *new_expired_tasks* column for it's related *order_id* in the **dispersal_table**

I am thinking there are at least two ways to do this:

1. After updating all expired rows, return the updated rows, and then iterate through
   it, increasing the expired_task column counter, per row updated with
   the related order_id
2. Make a trigger, that,each time the status column in a row in
   **task_pool** is updated to -1(expired), in **dispersal_table**, increases column expired_task by 1 in the row with related order_id

Unfortunately I am not sure how to implement this for either, and there may be a better way of doing this anyways.

---

Example:

Here there are two rows that will be updated to -1(expired) with order_id 30. Then in the dispersal_table, in row with order_id 30, column *new_expired_tasks* should increase by 2.

**task_pool** table

| id(key) | order_id (int) | user_id(int) | expire_time (timestamp) | status(int) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 30 | 12 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | 0 |
| 25 | 31 | 101 | 2024-08-14 19:19:04.032834 | 0 |
| 26 | 30 | 101 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | 0 |

**task_dispersal** table

| id(key) | order_id (int) | *new_expired_tasks* (int) | minimum_dipsersal(int) | amount_to_dipserse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 30 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 12 | 31 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

query:

```
UPDATE task_pool 
SET status = -1 
WHERE 
    status = 0 AND expire_time < current_timestamp
    OR
    status = 1 AND expire_time + (10 * interval '1 minute') < current_timestamp
```

*when the query is made, let's say the current_timestamp is 2024-05-15 19:19:05, which is past the expire time for row 24 and row 26.

Both of those rows have order_id of 30.

The new_expired_tasks counter in the row with order_id 30 in task_dispersal is increased for each row updated (2 times)*

| id(key) | order_id (int) | user_id(int) | expire_time (timestamp) | status(int) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 30 | 12 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | *-1 (just updated from 0)* |
| 25 | 31 | 101 | 2024-08-14 19:19:04.032834 | 0 |
| 26 | 30 | 101 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | *-1 (just updated from 0)* |

**task_dispersal** table

| id(key) | order_id (int) | *new_expired_tasks* (int) | minimum_dipsersal(int) | amount_to_dipserse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 30 | *2 (increased by 2)* | 1 | 0 |
| 12 | 31 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: PS. The reason I need to update new_expired_tasks RIGHT when rows in task_pool are set to expired, instead of just checking how many are expired when I query task_dipseral , is because I need to know the amount of rows that have been expired SINCE I last queried task_dispersal,

Comment: You can keep the status column off the table and instead set up a view. That way if you interface with the table through the view, you can make it add the column on the fly. Whenever you select from the view, you get the current status. `dispersal_table` also doesn't have to be a table, but instead a view that if you select from it, it adds a `sum()filter(where status=-1) as expired_tasks`.

Comment: If you want to analyse things happening over time, set up a table that collects events with their timestamps. No need to constantly poll and balance between granularity (polling more often to approach real time) and performance (polling less, because it's resource-intensive). Instead, if something's supposed to expire in the future, you just insert an event with a timestamp in the future. Then, the view that's supposed to reflect the current state of things can compare event timestamps to `now()`/`current_timestamp` and based on that decide what's expired and for how long exactly.

Comment: Oh man. I am a novice to postgres, sql in general. I would have to redo my whole project as it's all based around polling and updating that way. Thank you for the info though, I hope it sets me on the path to do this the right way.

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CsqAg7BY). As to recurring jobs/time-triggerred tasks, you can use `pg_cron` extension from within the db, or `cron`/`at`/`schtasks` from the OS and let those fire scripts that just do `psql -c 'update a set x=y where cond;'`. [Here's a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74604830/5298879).

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
with param as(select '2024-05-15 19:19:05'::timestamp test_timestamp)
,upd as(
  UPDATE task_pool 
    SET status = -1 
  from param
 WHERE status = 0 AND expire_time < test_timestamp
    OR status = 1 AND (expire_time + (10 * interval '1 minute'))<test_timestamp
  returning *
)
update task_dispersal
  set new_expired_tasks=updg.cnt
from(select order_id,count(*)cnt from upd group by order_id)updg
where task_dispersal.order_id=updg.order_id
returning *
```

Subquery returns

| id | order_id | user_id | expire_time | status | test_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 30 | 12 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | -1 | 2024-05-15 19:19:05 |
| 26 | 30 | 101 | 2024-05-14 19:19:04.032834 | -1 | 2024-05-15 19:19:05 |

Query returns

| id | order_id | new_expired_tasks | minimum_dipsersal | amount_to_dipserse | order_id | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 30 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 30 | 2 |

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to understand sql more! 
So, the first WITH wouldn't be needed in my query as I will just use current_timestamp, but I do understand why you put that there. to match my example.

What you are doing is returning all rows that have been updated,
and then getting the count of rows with the same order_id,
and then updating the new_expired_tasks column that's related to that order id.

This would be more efficient than a trigger too ,right?

Comment: Yes, CTE params - only for take timestamp. This is better than trigger.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this! Can I just ask in addition, do you think the update task_pool subquery could be optimized? 
```
   WHERE status = 0 AND expire_time < test_timestamp
    OR 
status = 1 AND (expire_time + (10 * interval '1 minute'))<test_timestamp
```
I can make a new question about this if it's not allowed to ask another question in the comments here. Thanks again!

Comment: I think, if you have an index on expire_time, there is no concern about efficiency at the moment. You can write ``OR status = 1 AND expire_time <(test_timestamp- (10 * interval '1 minute'))``

Comment: Hmm. I don't have an index on them now. I could add one though. Thanks!